# Batch file doesnot shows pop up

Tags: batch-file, command-line, vbscript, popup, scheduled-tasks

I have created a batch file which shows a pop up and i have scheduled the file to run everyday at 7 pm from task scheduler. The file works at the mentioned time but the pop up does not appear on desktop. I don't know what is wrong with it . When i tested without task scheduler the pop was appearing and after scheduling it just does not appear. The code i am using for pop up is as follows:

```
`    echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs

echo WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "The system will shutdown in 15 minutes, Click OK to ABORT !!" , 900 ,"Shutdown", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs

cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
 del %tmp%\tmp.vbs`
```

Comment: Are you running the task as the logged on user? The task won't be able to access the desktop when run using the system account.

Comment: @PMF i dont know how to run the task as logged on user. I am scheduling the task with a batch file using system context. How do i make it run as logged on user???? below is the batch code from which m scheduling the task

schtasks /create /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SC DAILY /ST 12:20 /TN "PoP_UP" /TR "c:\Windows\Temp\Shutdowntest.vbs" /IT /F

Comment: @Khushi: Not sure, but I guess you should replace the "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" with the name of the logged in user. Obviously, that doesn't work if you want it to work regardless of which user has logged on. In general, I guess using a vbscript is anyway not needed. Check this instead: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-schedule-computer-to-shut-down-at-a-certain/800ed207-f630-480d-8c92-dff2313c193b or just google for "windows shutdown at specific time".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a specific reason to use Task Scheduler, but it might be easier to add it to the run registry instead?

you can have it run on all users:

> REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Pop
>   up" /t REG_SZ /d "c:\Windows\Temp\Shutdowntest.vbs" /f

This will run on startup for each user who logs in.